# how to import nodejs module as library

Tags: node.js

I create my project "data" and I want to use it as a library in an another project. For this, I did the following steps:

1. `cd project`
2. `yarn add ../../packages/data` (the path of my project) It adds a new dependency in package.json like this "@info/data": "../../packages/data"
3. to install this dependency I run `yarn install`
   but it doesn't appear in node_modules and I don't know why
   Any help please

Comment: You should publish data first...

Comment: hi thanks for your reponse, what did you mean by publishing? sorry it's my first time, I don't get the idea

Answer (score 0):

For that you will have to create an npm module, there is a step by step availabe on the official documents here: [creating-node-js-modules](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules)

And, apart from creating the directory where your code will be placed and the exports for each method, you will also have to publish your module: [npm-publish](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-publish)

Comment: thanks for your help, I search for another way to use library locally without publish?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `npm` to publish your library to all npm users or to yourself

1. To do this, enter `npm login` in the terminal of the code editor and
   log in, before that, register on npm
2. If you haven't initialized the project then do it `npm init`
3. After you publish the library to the npm server, `npm publish`, remember the name of the library will take the name of the folder
4. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ufwbp838yZA  Example

perhaps yarn also has such a function

Comment: thanks for your help, I search for another way to use library locally without publish?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but it seems you can only publish it for yourself